# android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@27773032 is not valid; is your activity running?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-layout, android-studio, android-alertdialog

**Error** : android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@27773032 is not valid; is your activity running?

code

```
@Override
public void showInviteDialog(final IncomingInvite incomingInvite) {
    //  setCallAlert2(incomingInvite);

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            alertDialog = Dialog.createInviteDialog(incomingInvite.getInviter(),
                    acceptCallClickListener(incomingInvite), rejectCallClickListener(incomingInvite),
                    HomeActivity.this);
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });

}
```

Tried Solutions

```
  if(!isFinishing()){

            alertDialog = Dialog.createInviteDialog(incomingInvite.getInviter(),
                    acceptCallClickListener(incomingInvite), rejectCallClickListener(incomingInvite),
                    HomeActivity.this);
            alertDialog.show();
        }
```

Output :  No Crash . but no **Alert**.

Checked similar questions but i donot find any exact solution, all are for avoiding crash (like checking activity present or not etc). Not for showing alert.

**Note : Must show alert.**

Answer (score 0):

Here's what's happening.  You have an activity that is killed- either due to configuration change or due to the activity being ended naturally- before you try to show the alert.  Because your activity is dead, it has no right to show an alert.  Thus the exception.  The finishing check (or just a catch and ignore) will fix the crash by not trying to show the alert.

If your activity was killed normally, there's nothing to do here.  This is expected, a dead activity shouldn't be showing a dialog.  If its a recreation due to configuration change (like a rotation), then the new activity needs to be the one to show the dialog.  If this is due to loading data, you need to use a Loader or similar technique to make sure the old activity can access the load data from the original.  This applies to any asynchronous data coming from a server-  the new Activity needs to be the one to recieve it, not the old one.

Comment: in Service , loading  datas. but acivtity  and fragments still visible.. isFinishing()  results true.

Comment: You can't show a dialog from a service.  You need to send a message to the activity, and have it display the dialog.

Comment: not shown dailog from service. dialog shown from activity. showInviteDialog() inside activity